# This.Page.Request reading incomplete encoded params c#

Tags: c#, request, webrequest, parameters

I have this problem,

This Request["MyParam"] working , but this method have a problem with Encoded values from a webrequest like : MyParam=help & development , I get just the 'help' word, someone have an Idea to resolve that issue ?

Comment: You should be encoding the ampersand when generating the link..

Comment: The query string `?MyParam=help & development` is malformed.  Given that query string, the value of `MyParam` is `help`... which is what you're seeing.

Comment: On Url the param gets the encoded param : help%20%26%20development , I think that is ok but I still getting just the 'helpword'

Answer (score 0):

`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` is used to convert the string into an array of bytes, which is what the `WebRequest` API expects.

Can also take help of this link:

http://tech.top21.de/techblog/20100421-solving-problems-with-request-parameter-encoding.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, But Url param I get the correct encoded param as UTF-8 : help%20%26%20development , I think that is ok, but I still getting just the 'help' word, maybe I need to read a full url params request ? Thanks